# Inserting or Updating tables between two different sql servers with same database name and table name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012

I have to perform insert/update of tables on clicking a "Promote" Button in the  UI, from the tables in the SQL Server of development to SQL Server of Live.

I have to compare the data between the tables and then do insertion or updation of the records. I am using asp.net MVC 4 and SQL server 2014.
Can anyone provide a better solution?

I tried the SQLBulk Copy, but it just dumps all the records without checking for duplicates.

Comment: How are you interacting with each database now?

Comment: currently iam using the ADO.Net classes for interaction.i am not using the entity framework classes.